# How can I add on every input a currency symbol at the end?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a input Field and when a user types anything I want to show a € Symbol behind.

exp: 10.50€

```
          <Input
            keyboardType='numeric'
            onChangeText={handleChangePrice}
            value={shipping.price.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })}
          />
```

this code above is not working. has anyone a solution for this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the symbol at the end of the text input or you can append it every time the price is changed.

1. https://snack.expo.dev/@sadiac/excited-edamame
2. `value={shipping.price + "€"}`

Comment: Let me know if you this does not help.

Comment: this will not work nicely because cursor will move after "€" symbol